# UITextView editable and link detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone UITextView does not support data detectors when the text view is editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097340/iphone-uitextview-does-not-support-data-detectors-when-the-text-view-is-editable)

Why is it that when I do:

cell.title.editable = YES;

the link detection is off? Is there a way to have this on with it being editable?

Comment: It seems that other people tried that without good results. See this [S.O. question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097340/iphone-uitextview-does-not-support-data-detectors-when-the-text-view-is-editable). Sorry for the negative answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **dataDetectorTypes**  propery of [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) to enable the auto dection of URL , numbers etc..

```
MyTextview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink ;
```

The possible values which can be assigned to dataDetectorTypes .
`UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber`,`UIDataDetectorTypeLink` [more](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I did that already, but when you do that and make the editable to YES, it's like it disables the whole thing, try it if you don't trust me

Comment: @adit : I think you should follow the link provided by @sergio, it address the same issue as yours .