# UITextView dataDetector is not working in tableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a UITextView in a TableViewCell and I wanted to enable data detection in the textView in order to show clickable links and Phone numbers.
So I did this in storyBoard

[image: Behaviour: Editable, DataDetectors : Link,Phone Number]

[image: User Interaction enabled]

These steps didn't work so I did the same in code.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var postDescTextView: UITextView!

 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    postDescTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    postDescTextView.isSelectable = true
    postDescTextView.dataDetectorTypes = .all

}
```

But none of the steps seems to work.

[image: Simulator Screen Shot]

There is clearly something I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty sure the answer is a simple one. I've found some similar questions like these.
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097340/iphone-uitextview-does-not-support-data-detectors-when-the-text-view-is-editable)
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306751/uitextview-inside-uitableviewcell-touch-go-through-if-not-clicking-on-a-link)

But unlike these questions, I don't want my TextView editable nor I don't want to be able to select The TableViewCell. Just need to make the Datalink detection work in a TableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make `postDescTextView` programmatically remove everything else and add the following.

```
postDescTextView.isEditable = false
postDescTextView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
```

Or if you have a storyboard

[image]

Note: If you're using the programmatic approach there is no need for giving it in `viewDidLayout` which gets called every time there's a layout change. Give it in the `init` method instead.